# Why can't I change the hostname of my server using sudo?

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

From a user that is part of the sudoers group, I can normally run any command by doing `sudo <command>`

But the following command fails stating "Permission denied"

```
sudo echo "myhostname" > /etc/hostname
```

It doesn't even ask me for the password. How do I change the hostname ?

Comment: And if you're on a new version of Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/a/516898/158442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct command in your case will be `echo "newhostname" | sudo tee /etc/hostname`, because as nssnd explained, `sudo` applies only to single command, and redirection has less priority than `sudo`. Another option is to use `bash` command:

```
sudo bash -c "echo newhostname > /etc/hostname"
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` applies only to your first command, so the ">" operation is done from your user.

To run your command:

1. get a root shell by executing `sudo -i`
2. execute your command: `echo "myhostname" > /etc/hostname`
3. exit the root shell with `exit`